# adjacency matrix, maximal eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm given a $d$ regular graph $G$. Dentote by $A(G)$ the adjacency matrix of $G$. I have to show that $\lambda_{\max}=d$, where $\lambda_{\max}$ is the biggest eigenvalue of $A(G)$.

I know that the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A(G)$ with eigenvalue $d$ but I cannot show that that this eigenvalue is indeed the maximal one.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: "Where $\lambda_{\max} is . . ." etc. I wonder if you can explain why you treat this occurrence of the word "where" as if it were the beginning of a sentence, using a capital rather than lower-case "W", and a period before it. I've seen that frequently here for years. Did some style manual tell you to do it that way?

Answer (score 11):

A more general result is that the eigenvalues of an adjacency matrix are bounded above by the maximum degree of the vertices.

Let $M(G)$ be the maximum degree of all the vertices, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A(G)=(a_{ij})$ with corresponding eigenvector $v=(v_1,\cdots, v_n)$. Rescale $v$ such that $|v_k|\leq 1$ for all $k$.

Now, we have that 
\begin{align*}
|\lambda|&=|\lambda v_i|\\
&=\left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^na_{ij}v_j\right|\\
&\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}||v_j| \\
&\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}| \\
&\leq M(G).
\end{align*}